# Bypassing OAuth in Traefik router that routes to other network device

Tags: docker, authentication, traefik

In Traefik2, I've got `router.toml` that contains the following lines:

```
[http.routers]
    [http.routers.sonarr-bypass]
        rules = "Host(`sonarr.DOMAIN.com`) && Headers(`traefik-auth-bypass-key`, `thekey`)"
        middleware = ["chain-no-auth"]
        service = "sonarr"
        [http.routers.sonarr-bypass.tls]
    [http.routers.sonarr]
        rule = "Host(`sonarr.DOMAIN.com`)"
        middlewares = ["chain-oauth"]
        service = "sonarr"
        [http.routers.sonarr.tls]
    
[http.services]
    [http.services.sonarr.loadBalancer]
        [[http.services.sonarr.loadBalancer.servers]]
            url = "http://192.168.50.51:8989"
```

The `chain-no-auth` and `chain-oauth` middlewares work elsewhere, like in my `docker-compose.yml`, but the above sends me to my OAuth server regardless of my headers when accessing the URL `sonarr.DOMAIN.com`.

Am I missing something? Perhaps I need to set the priority?

Comment: Okay, I put `rules` instead of `rule` since there was more than one condition. That was it. Dumb me.

Answer (score 0):

I put `rules` instead of `rule` since there was more than one condition. That was it. All working now.